# Pandas dataframe plotting

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot Temperature vs Year from a dataframe.  This is my code:

```
dfs =[]
for a in data():
    for b in data():
        tempDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=colNames)
        tempDataFrame['Temp']= var.Temp
        tempDataFrame['Year']= var.Year
        dfs.append(tempDataFrame)

        traces.append(go.scatter(x=dfs['Year'],y=dfs['Temp']))
 normData=pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
 return traces
```

Output: Keep getting this error.

```
traces.append(go.scatter(x=dfs['Year'],y=dfs['Temp']))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: But here `dfs` is a **list**???

Comment: It's telling you that `dfs` is a list

Answer (score 0):

Use this to initialize your variables:

```
dfs = pd.DataFrame()
traces = pd.DataFrame()
```